# how to call a function in a parent controller (angularjs1.6)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-1.6

how to call a function in a children controller (angularjs1.6)?

My parent controller which is in a component:

```
class myParentController { 
constructor() {}
parentFunction() {

 }
}
```

And my children controller which is in another component:

```
class myChildrenController {
constructor() {}
childrenFunction() {

 }
}
```

how to call parentFunction in childrenFunction?

Comment: super.parentFunction()

Comment: `super`is used when it comes to a static function

Comment: use $scope.$parent.parentFunction()

Comment: 'super' can be used on non-static functions too, see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: Finaly in angular1.6 for talk between a parent function with a children function we need a bindings, it's more easier.